# Multiple Duplicate Data points- Angularjs Rxjs Subscription Not Working As Expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and can't seem to understand what I've been doing wrong. I have to access a URL that looks like this with SOMENUMBERHERE possibly having new points added on the backend.

`https//myURL/globalData/SOMENUMBERHERE/DATAFORNUMBERSELECTED`

I am able to access it with what I am doing but the output is pulling the same data multiple times. There should only be 50 data points but I receive close to 100. I am not familiar with how to step through code on front end so I have been trying console.log on everything. I can't seem to find a solution to this.

I have this in my service.ts file to get data from off the server. First method to get the list of numbers and second method to add that number to the end of the url

```
getData(): Observable<any>{
   return this.http
    .get<any>(this.myGlobalChainURL)
    .pipe(res => res);

    }

getGlobalData(resultNum): Observable<any>{

  return this.http
    .get<any>(this.myGlobalChainURL + resultNum)
    .pipe(res => res);
}
```

My code to populate a chart looks like this:

```
this.apiService.getData().subscribe(result => {
  result.forEach(element => {
    this.apiService.getGlobalData(element).subscribe(res => {

      this.timeStamp.push(moment(res.Timestamp * 1000).format('HH:MM'));
       this.systemSix.push(res.FStates.LStates[0].Forms);

      //pass values to chart and draw it in chart function
      this.createChart(this.timeStamp, this.systemSix);

  });

});
});
```

What I don't understand is that this does work but for some reason I get duplicate data points. when I log timestamps I get outputs that look like this.

Response I am receiving:

```
20:01, 20:01, 22:01, 23:01
```

Expected Response:

```
20:01, 22:01, 23:01
```

If you can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: A suggestion that could help is to refactor your primary subscription to use observable composition and instead flatten the nested requests you need to make. This eliminates the loop inside your subscription handler, which looks suspicious. Something along the lines of: `this.apiService.getData().pipe(map(n => this.apiService.getGlobalData(n)), mergeAll()).subscribe(/* use results one at a time: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, ... 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, ... */)`.

Comment: In your service, you can get rid of `.pipe(res => res)`, pretty sure they do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I will try these things out. I am new to using a service.

Comment: @miqh is there a resource for how to flatten? I am having issues with my .push and createChart method with mergeAll() I am not sure how I can use the results one at a time inside the .subscribe()

Comment: @Daniella, yep, the official RxJS documentation should have some examples for every operator (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api). I also made a quick sandbox to show you the effect of flattening nested requests (https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-xuij1).